# does red knob and tube wire have a specific functio

Tags: electrical

My home built in 1939 with k&t wire.
Has black,white and red wire.
Does the red have a more specific funtion than the black?

Comment: Do some fixtures, receptacles, etc. have black and white and some have black and red? Or are black and red used together?

Comment: Usually a black and red wire will be for two hots for a 240 volt circuit, like for ovens/stoves, dryers.  Just a black and white is for 120 volts for household receptacles/outlets and lights.  Unknown if K&T circuits used MWBC(two 120 with a common neutral).  Also unknown is if this circuit was done by code or someone just added wrong wire colours, maybe as a ground.  Pictures of the connections will help.

Comment: Check out with a multimeter.

Comment: +1 for checking it with a multimeter. At best colors are a hint about the original installer's intent; someone later may have done something unexpected. "Trust but verify".

Comment: Thanks much for your responses, im sure this is all original and in good co ndition i. Updating as i go.

Comment: I seem to remember red to switches, have only opened up a few places